# ie 8 settings on a server

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet-explorer

Anyone know how to start the wizard that goes through the series of IE 8 configurations when it is first installed? I somehow dismissed it and now I'm getting Windows Update suggesting that I download the compatibility view list. This is a waste of time for a server and I'm not sure what other settings I missed that need to be turned off for an IE 8 instance on a windows server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want Internet Explorer to display the Internet Connection Wizard again:

1. Open Regedit
2. Go to this key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Connection Wizard\Completed
3. Set the value to 0